# Javascript array becomes null

Tags: javascript, arrays

I defined two-dimensional array, tried to fill it in nested loop, but it fill only first dimension with right values, other dimensions are filled with null(or undefined), thanks.

```
var Arr = [];
var i =0;

for(i=0;i<13;i++)
{
  Arr[i]=[];
}

var a=0,b=0;

for(a=0;a<13;a++)
{
  for(b=0;b<13;b++)
  {
    Arr[[a][b]]=AnotherArrWithRightValues[(13 * a) + b];
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `Arr[a][b]=AnotherArrWithRightValues[(13 * a) + b];`

Comment: isn't `Arr[a][b]`?

Comment: you have a syntax error:
Arr[a][b] =AnotherArrWithRightValues[(13 * a) + b];

Comment: where is AnotherArrWithRightValues defined ?

Comment: AnotherAWRV is global array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arr[[a][b]]` should be  `Arr[a][b]`

Comment: @Mohsen How so?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi really! how's that? this Arr[[a][b]] is syntax error !

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi That's what is expected

Answer (score 1):

Loksly's answer is correct, but implemented in a different way. To answer your question, replace `Arr[[a][b]]` with `Arr[a][b]`.

---

Full Code :

```
var Arr = [];

for(var a = 0 ; a < 13 ; a++) {
  Arr[a] = [];
  for(var b = 0 ; b < 13 ; b++) {
    Arr[a][b]=AnotherArrWithRightValues[(13 * a) + b];
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly like mine

Comment: Simultaneously written !

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, another way to achieve the same:

```
var Arr = [];
var i = 0, tmp;
var a, b;

for(a = 0; a < 13; a++){
    tmp = [];
    for(b = 0; b < 13; b++){
        tmp.push(AnotherArrWithRightValues[i++]);
    }
    Arr.push(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var arr =[];

for(var a=0;a<13;a++)
  {
    arr[a] = new Array();
    for(var b=0;b<13;b++)
      {
        arr[a].push((13 * a) + b);
      }
  }
```

i hope this will help you